# convert excel spreadsheet with format to markdown

Tags: microsoft-excel, conversion, spreadsheet, markdown, plaintext

I want to convert a spreadsheet table with basic formatting (bold, script) to MD (markdown) format.

I know howto convert a table to Markdown but it losses the basic format and i need to preserve it.

In some text editors I can paste a HTML code and it contains the format but HTML from excel long and complex, so I can't see how process and convert.

Example of table

[image]

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: What kind of file format did you use?

Comment: I have tried several services on Internet and some support tables and format but it seems that the failure is on the copied data to the clipboard. From excel the copy/paste from a xlsx file format,seems to paste unformatted plain text or an image. However from Libreoffice calc it paste always text

Comment: If you edit your question to include a sample screenshot of your data in Excel, I can give you a more targeted example in [my answer](https://superuser.com/a/1787111/)

Answer (score 0):

My converter of choice is the [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#) and, like your own experience, Excel and Sheets data is pasted in plain text.

I don't have a tool to interpret the formatting and convert it to markdown formatting however I use the following workaround.

I prepare my data with the markdown formatting. I write formulas to add markdown code.

- For a range of bold text in Sheets, I might use
  `=ARRAYFORMULA("**"&A1:G1&"**")`
- italics would be `"*"` instead of `"**"`
- line breaks can be replaced by `<br>` and so forth.

Depending on the complexity of what you are converting this may be adequate until you find a better option.